# Is there a way to set a timeout for the entire program after a click?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

What I'm intending to do is
60 seconds after the user clicks `test`, alert the user with a message. How exactly would I go about this? Setting a `setTimeout` for the whole code doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test your click speed | Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
    <script src="js/test.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ="count-div">
      <p>Count:</p>
      <p class="count"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="supercenter">
        <section class="info">
            <p class="welcome">Welcome to the test!</p>
            <p>The test shall begin in <span class="counter">5</span></p>
        </section>
        <section class="test">
            <div class="clickspace">
                <h1>Click Here</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:#333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body{
    background:hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.884);
}
.count-div{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:none;
}
.count-div p{
    color: white;
    display: inline;
}
.supercenter{
    height:100vh;
    display:flex; 
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
.info{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:25px;
}
p:first-child{
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
p:nth-of-type(2){
    font-weight:700;
}
.test{
    display: none;
}
.clickspace{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:white;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.clickspace:active{
    transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```js
const welcome = document.querySelector(".welcome");
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");
const info = document.querySelector(".info");
const test = document.querySelector(".test");
let countEl = document.querySelector(".count")
let countDiv = document.querySelector(".count-div")
let time = 5;
let count = 0;
let total = 0;
let timer = 0;
const countDown = setInterval(() => {
    time--;
    counter.textContent = time;
    if(time<0){
        counter.textContent = "0"
        info.style.display = "none";
        test.style.display = "contents"
        countDiv.style.display = "contents"
    }
}
,1000)
test.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count++; 
    total=count;
    countEl.textContent=total;
})
```

Comment: Add your HTML, please.

Comment: So put the setTimeout inside of the click?

Comment: Hi there! I have just added the HTML and the CSS

Comment: So is the message shown once? Is the message shown multiple times? Is the message shown multiple times, but after the first one (aka it waits another 60 after the first one is clicked)? You need to add more to what you expect so people know the correct way to code it.

Comment: The message should be shown once. You can view a demo of this at https://clickspeedtest.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event handler with once and it will only be called once.

```js
const test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("done");
  }, 2000 /*60000*/);
}, {once: true});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="test">Click</button>
```

Or use a Boolean

```js
let clicked = false;
const test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!clicked) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("done");
    }, 2000 /*60000*/);
    clicked = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="test">Click</button>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, which method would be considered better?

Comment: Depends on the situation. First one you would need to rebind an event if you want to reuse it. Second one you just have to reset the boolean.

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
test.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("60 seconds have passed");
  }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user keeps clicking the button?

Comment: @RyanWilson An alert shows 60 seconds after each click

Comment: I'm not sure having the `alert` fire multiple times is desired.

Comment: @RyanWilson You are making assumptions :)

Comment: @epascarello Can say the same for the answer. :)

Comment: Answer did want OP asked. "60 seconds after the user clicks test, alert the user with a message"

Comment: Hey there! Yes indeed, it is not desired. I simply want it to show up once.

Comment: An example of this can be viewed at https://clickspeedtest.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cancel any previous timer that was running each time the button is clicked, you can set a variable to hold the timeout ID and clear it.

```js
let clickTimeout
let test = document.querySelector('button');
test.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    clearTimeout(clickTimeout)
    clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
       alert("60 seconds have passed");
    }, 60000);
})
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```